# Why LIST ALL USER OF ROLE command reported error in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using the  `LIST ALL USER OF ROLE` command in Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB, and it seems like this statement cannot be executed successfully and an error reported. Is this function no longer supported in IoTDB? How can I continue this checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `LIST ALL USER OF ROLE` command is changed to `LIST USER OF ROLE` in Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB, so you can change your statement and try again.